# Coq: Defining a special function

Tags: function, coq

I want to define a function `f` w/ 2 explicit arguments. The types of the arguments and value of `f` are applications of some `g`. Suppose the arguments' types are `g x y` and `g z w`. The tricky part is that **`f`'s value must depend on the unifiability of `x` and `z`**. Below is a naive attempt at defining `f` that fails. How should I tackle this?

```
Inductive A := a | a0 | fa.
Inductive B := b | b0.
Parameter C: Type.
Parameter g: A -> B -> C.
Parameter CT:> C -> Type.
Parameter gab: g a b.
Parameter ga0b: g a0 b.

Definition f {x y z w}(n: g x y)(m: g z w) :=
ltac:(match x with z => exact (g z b) | _  => exact (g fa b) end).

Compute f gab ga0b. (*= g fa b: C*)
Compute f gab gab. (*! = g fa b: C !*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `f`'s value must depend on the unifiability of `x` and `z`

It is impossible to write such a definition.  Suppose you could write a function that could tell whether or not two natural numbers unified, call it `unify_nat : nat -> nat -> bool`.  Consider now the functions

```
F := fun x y : nat => if unify_nat (x + y) (y + x) then True else False
G := fun x y : nat => if unify_nat (x + y) (x + y) then True else False
```

We can prove, because addition is commutative, that `forall x y, F x y = G x y`.  But then `unify_nat (x + y) (y + x)` must return `true`, even though `x + y` and `y + x` do not unify.

---

There are two things you can do: (1) you can ask not if the terms unify, but if they are propositionally equal; and (2) you can write a notation, or an alias, which is like syntactic sugar for a definition.

**1.**

The command `Scheme Equality` will generate an equality decision function for most inductive types:

```
Scheme Equality for A.
Definition f {x y z w}(n: g x y)(m: g z w) :=
  if A_beq x z then g z b else g fa b.

Compute f gab ga0b. (*= g fa b: C*)
Compute f gab gab. (*= g a b: C*)
```

**2.**

We can create evars with `open_constr:(_)` and use unification to infer the types of `n` and `m`:

```
Ltac f_tac n m :=
  let x := open_constr:(_) in
  let y := open_constr:(_) in
  let z := open_constr:(_) in
  let w := open_constr:(_) in
  let n := constr:(n : g x y) in
  let m := constr:(m : g z w) in
  match x with z => exact (g z b) | _  => exact (g fa b) end.
Notation f n m := (ltac:(f_tac n m)) (only parsing).

Compute f gab ga0b. (*= g fa b: C*)
Compute f gab gab. (*= g a b: C*)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I take the point that unification may become impossible if a commutative operation is defined on a type the terms of which I want to unify. But I must unify terms of a type w/ no operations defined on it

Comment: It has nothing to do with commutativity; that was just a convenient example.  Consider `fun x y => unify x y`.  Suppose `unify x y` gave `false ` for opaque distinct variables `x` and `y`; then `unify x x` must also give `false ` because `(fun x y => unify x y) x x` is convertible with `unify x x`.  You can decide equality in Gallina, but unifiability is invisible.

Comment: IIUC unifiability implies equality but I agree that equality is more universal and decidable in Gallina while unifiability (as the commutativity example showed) somewhat opaque. I'm not sure about your last example, though, since `Parameter x y: Set. Check ltac:(unify x x). Fail Check (fun x y => ltac:(unify x y)) x x. (*not unifiable*) Fail Check ltac:(refine ((fun x y => ltac:(unify x y)) x x)). (*not unifiable*) Check ltac:(let t := (fun x y => unify x y) in t x x).`

Comment: These are not Gallina functions. Coq has two very different languages: Ltac, and Gallina. Unifiability is completely invisible from inside Gallina. It is impossible to write a *Gallina function* whose output value depends on a unification problem. That is, you cannot have a definition `f : A -> B` where `f x = f y` iff `x` and `y` unify. Ltac is a tactic language for creating Gallina terms. It executes during type inference.  Once you have a closed, type-checked Gallina term, all Ltac must be gone. Although unifiability is invisible from Gallina, it is visible during type inference, in Ltac.

Comment: OK, thanks. As I've written my development alternately in Gallina and Ltac, I was confused as to what you meant by "impossible to write such a definition"

Comment: Noticed that **2.** doesn't work as expected: `Compute f gab ga0b. (*= g a0 b: C*)`

Comment: @jaam What version of Coq are you using?  `Compute f gab ga0b.` gives me ` = g fa b : C` in Coq master and 8.7.1.  In Coq 8.6.1 it gives `g a0 b`, due to some issues with Ltac evaluation, but if you replace the `match` with `first [ unify x z; exact (g z b) | exact (g fa b) ]`, then it works fine in 8.6 as well as 8.7 and 8.8.

Comment: I used 8.6.1. It's settled, then